# Can't write the subscript in expression in R

Tags: r, label, expression

I'm trying to create a `ylab` for my plot in m/s^2.

```
plot(mydata[,1], mydata[,3], type  = "l", xlab="Time [s]", ylab=expression("Acceleration [m/s"^{2}"]"), 
     main="Example of signal of horizontal acceleration", cex.main = 0.9)
```

The problem is after the `^` symbol `]` gets superscripted.

[image]

with my code I get this error,

```
> source('~/Dropbox/WORK/ISRProject/R_projects/plots_report.R')
Error in source("~/Dropbox/WORK/ISRProject/R_projects/plots_report.R") : 
  ~/Dropbox/WORK/ISRProject/R_projects/plots_report.R:26:99: unexpected ']'
25: 
26: plot(mydata[,1], mydata[,3], type  = "l", xlab="Time [s]", ylab=expression("Acceleration [m/s"^{2}"]"
                                                                                                     ^
```

Comment: `expression(paste("Acceleration [ ", m/s^2, " ]"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `ylab=expression(paste("Acceleration [ ",m/s^{2}," ]"))`

```
par(mar=c(4,5,4,4))
x <- seq(1,10,.01)
plot(x, sin(pi/2*x), type  = "l", xlab="Time [s]", 
     ylab=expression(paste("Acceleration [ ",m/s^{2}," ]")), 
     main="Example of signal of horizontal acceleration", cex.main = 0.9)
```

[image]